# I get a TypeError in an on_message event in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
    @bot.event()
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'
```

My code:

> main.py

```
#------importing packages

import keep_alive
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-', case_insensitive=True)


my_token = os.environ['Token']

#------When bot is online


@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    #status
    #playing game status

    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(
        name=f'On {len(bot.guilds)} Servers | -help'))

    print('Bot is Ready')

@bot.event()
async def on_message(message):
    # if message.content.startswith(bot.user.mentioned_in(message)):
    #     await message.channel.send('My prefix is `-`')

    if message.content == ('hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello i am bot')


initial_extensions = ['math1', 'mod', 'weather', 'fun1', 'help']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        bot.load_extension(extension)


#ping latency....
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong\n{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms')


#------Running the bot
keep_alive.keep_alive()
bot.run(my_token)
```

I do not have multiple `on_message` events. there is only one `on_message` event which is in main.py. There is no other `on_message` event in any other files as well.

*Note:* If you would like to check out all my other files and their code, then please see [this link](https://replit.com/@NishilSheth/Shiny-disc-bot#main.py)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bot.event` should *not* be called

```py
@bot.event  # without the parenthesis
async def on_message(message):
    ...
```